# Combining Default Price & Special Price and build timeline

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I have 2 datasets which i need to combine/intersect.
I'm using Laravel collection for this.

**Default price-list**

- End-date is optional. Missing end-date means the price valid until further notice

| Item | Price per Item | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Milk | 10 | 1-Jan | 15-Jan |
| Milk | 11 | 16-Jan |  |

**Special price-list (per customer)**

- Special price will always have end-date

| Customer | Item | Price | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Milk | 8 | 2-Jan | 8-Jan |
| Mike | Milk | 8 | 9-Jan | 20-Jan |

This is my expected output *(for Adam)*

| Item | Price | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Milk | 10 | 1-Jan | 1-Jan |
| Milk | 8 | 2-Jan | 8-Jan |
| Milk | 10 | 9-Jan | 15-Jan |
| Milk | 11 | 16-Jan |  |

This is my expected output *(for Mike)*

| Item | Price | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Milk | 10 | 1-Jan | 8-Jan |
| Milk | 8 | 9-Jan | 20-Jan |
| Milk | 11 | 21-Jan |  |

My thought process (per customer) as below:-

1. Combined both list
2. Insert/Create another record based on the `end_date` and set it to next day (but i don't know the price)
3. Sort by `start_date`

Here's what i did so far (i going for Adam only, for now)

```php
$default = collect([
    ['item' => 'Milk', 'price' => 10, 'start_date' => Carbon::parse('2021-01-01'), 'end_date' => Carbon::parse('2021-01-15')],
    ['item' => 'Milk', 'price' => 9, 'start_date' => Carbon::parse('2021-01-16'), 'end_date' => null],
]);

$special = collect([
    ['item' => 'Milk', 'price' => 8, 'start_date' => Carbon::parse('2021-01-02'), 'end_date' => Carbon::parse('2021-01-05')],
]);

$combined = $default->merge($special);

$endDates = $combined->whereNotNull('end_date')->map(function($item, $key){
    return collect([
        'item' => 'Milk',
        'price' => $item['price'],
        'start_date' => $item['end_date']->addDay()->startOfDay(),
        'end_date' => null,
    ]);
});

$unsorted = $combined->merge($endDates);

$sorted = $unsorted->sortBy(function ($item, $key){
    return $item['start_date']->valueOf();
});

return $sorted->values()->all();
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you already have? What did you try? What failed?

Comment: @codedge i've added my code. Thx!